# How to add one more column while using codeigniter createlinks function?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web

I try to use the class pagination in codeigniter. It can help me easily get data from database.But Now I came across a problem that the createlinks() funciton of pagination only create corresponding columns for data stored in database. Now  I want to add one more column in the table to add modify/delete links for the corresponding row in the table?How can achieve this goal?

Comment: add some code that you have tried...

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it myself. Just iterate the result from $query->result from the database and add the links string as one column in the two dimensional array.Maybe there exits betters ways~~